# Find the column name of last not null value from a particular columns in a row in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, case, conditional-statements

I have a mysql Table is like this

```
  ID    status1        status2       status3         status4      date   

  1      busy           null        callagain         null      2014-11-28
  2      null           null          busy            null      2014-11-26
  3   notreachable      busy          null            null      2014-11-26
```

Where ID is the primary key.
I want to fetch the column name of last not null value in a row from status1,status2,status3,status4 columns and Result is like this

```
   ID    status
   1     status3
   2     status3
   3     status2
```

also i need a where cluase with this query where this result  status ='any_value'.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.id, (CASE WHEN a.status4 IS NOT NULL THEN 'status4' 
                   WHEN a.status3 IS NOT NULL THEN 'status3' 
                   WHEN a.status2 IS NOT NULL THEN 'status2' 
                   WHEN a.status1 IS NOT NULL THEN 'status1' 
                   ELSE NULL 
              END) AS colStatus
FROM tableA a;
```

For second question: **where this result status ='any_value'.**

```
SELECT a.id, a.status 
FROM (SELECT a.id, (CASE WHEN a.status4 IS NOT NULL THEN 'status4' 
                         WHEN a.status3 IS NOT NULL THEN 'status3' 
                         WHEN a.status2 IS NOT NULL THEN 'status2' 
                         WHEN a.status1 IS NOT NULL THEN 'status1' 
                         ELSE NULL 
                   END) AS colSTATUS
      FROM tableA a
     ) AS A 
WHERE a.status IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT ID ,
          COALESCE( CASE
                        WHEN status4 IS NOT NULL THEN 'status4'
                        ELSE NULL
                    END ,
                    CASE
                        WHEN status3 IS NOT NULL THEN 'status3'
                        ELSE NULL
                    END ,
                    CASE
                        WHEN status2 IS NOT NULL THEN 'status2'
                        ELSE NULL
                    END ,
                    CASE
                        WHEN status1 IS NOT NULL THEN 'status1'
                        ELSE NULL
                    END ,
                    NULL ) AS colstatus
       FROM table1 ) AS DERIVEDTABLE
WHERE colstatus = 'status3'
```

ciao!

Comment: thanks. But it does not work. I got status4 as field name for all data